# js.node - using axl

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I am trying to run an axl query against cucm.
I have a working example(shamelessly stolen) here:
https://gist.github.com/darrenparkinson/9978397
I'm trying to be simple and replace the soap portion with a sql query which, when I use curl to send the request looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <axlapi:executeSQLQuery sequence="1"
    xmlns:axlapi="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0"
    xmlns:axl="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0 axlsoap.xsd">
            <sql>select count(*) from device</sql>
    </axlapi:executeSQLQuery>
```

When I attempt this with node.js I get

node device.js
        SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Here is the soap portion I attempted to send with node.js:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: FWIW you might be better off using an actual SOAP client instead of trying to rely on hand-stitching together XML (and hope it continues to work in the future).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a format a try, this works for me using [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/%20%22SoapUI)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:executeSQLQuery sequence="?">
         <sql>select count(*) from device</sql>
      </ns:executeSQLQuery>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```